# What do you call it when a satellite goes once around its planet?

Tags: natural-satellites, terminology

When a planet or a satellite turns around itself, its called a rotation. When a planet goes once around the Sun, it's called a revolution. What do you call it when a satellite goes once around its planet? Is it also a revolution? But then how do you disambiguate with the satellite having gone once around the Sun?

Comment: With one particular satellite, I call it a month. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Definitions](https://differencecamp.com/rotation-vs-revolution/):

> Rotation can be defined as the circular motion of an object around its own axis, or upon itself.
>
> Revolution can be defined as the circular movement of an object around an external axis, or around another body.

So a satellite moving around a planet once is called a revolution. Or an orbit. "The satellite stayed active for 3 orbits, and then the batteries ran out".

To disambiguate the case 'the satellite having gone once around the Sun': this depends. Is the satellite in orbit around a planet, or does it orbit the Sun directly?

If the satellite is in orbit around a planet, you have to describe what you mean. There's no separate word for this case, AFAIK.
If it's in orbit around the Sun, it's again one orbit or one revolution.